# What does it mean to put <> in code?

Tags: c#, .net

I am new to .NET C# and I was reading the code below:

```
var model = new TenantPageViewData<Tenant>(contentModel)
```

I can't understand `<MyClass>`, What does it mean to put `<>` in the code.
Also if you can guide me to documentation regarding this it will be great.

Comment: Generics. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the syntax for specifying the type parameter for an open generic type. You can read more about generics here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx

If you are new to C#, it will seem complicated at first, but a lot of the language makes use of this feature so it will be time *very* well spent learning it.

---

With the general documentation and answer out of the way, in this specific case, the `TenantPageViewData` exposes a generic parameter. You read that as "a `TenantPageViewData<>` of `Tenant`".

The signature for that class will look something like:

```
public class TenantPageViewData<T> 
{
}
```

Where `T` is simply a placeholder you can reference in code that will, at compile-time, become strongly-typed to the type of argument you specify.

This class definition can be referred to as an "open" generic type because the placeholder `T` is, as yet, unrealised. The declaration `var something = new TenantPageViewData<Tenant>()` is a "closed" generic type because the generic argument is known to now be `Tenant` in this instance.

Type identity is *per closed generic type*, so a `TenantPageViewData<Tenant>` is not a `TenantPageViewData<Landlord>`, and `static` members of a generic class honour this also (which is a common pitfall of learning generics).

---

Other examples include `List<string>` usually read as "a `List<>` of `string`", and the comical `Cup<T>` :-)

Answer (score 0):

these type of brackets I believe are used for marking generics.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In C#, the angle brackets (< and >) are most often used to enclose a parameter of a generic class.  For example, the .Net framework provides a List class where 'T' denotes the *type* of objects that will be contained in the list.  Therefore, when the list is created as

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
```

you are creating a usable, type-safe instance of the List class.

Some good info on it  [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x6a29h6.aspx).